# Cloudflare - Redirect DomainA to DomainB SSL Issue

Tags: cloudflare

we have two domains, A and B, where I'm looking to get DomainA to redirect all requests to DomainB. There is no server behind DomainA. I've followed this tutorial exactly as presented on Cloudflare:

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirecting-one-domain-to-another/81960

And it works just fine for non-https traffic. Attempting to go to https://domaina.com gives me `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` while http://domaina.com redirects to https://domainb.com just fine.

My page rules reflect the tutorial - that is `*domaina.com/*` 301 redirects to `https://domainb.com/$2`

My SSL options in Cloudflare is set to "Full". The orange clouds are on as well for both `@` and `www` on DomainA which currently are `A` records. I've tried `CNAME` as well. Has anyone else run into this before? What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Free Clouflare plan will give you "Free certificate".
The Free Certificate's Common Name is always pointed to `sni.cloudflaressl.com`.
You can't change the common name unless you order `Advanced Certificate Manager` for $10/month.

You can see Advanced Certificate Manager in SSL > Edge Certificates > Order Advanced Certificate:

[image: Advanced Certificate Manager in SSL/TLS > Edge Certificates > Order Advanced Certificate]

Sample "Free Certificate":

[image: SSL sample]

The certificate's common name is set to `sni.cloudflaressl.com` but it is valid to all major OS and browser because the `Subject Alternative Name (SAN)` in the certificate contains your domain.

Comment: Welp. If that's the case I'll just spin up a $5/month droplet and letsencrypt that bad boy. Thanks for the replies, this seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your SSL option to "Flexible" instead. Since your domain A doesn't have SSL setup, "Full" wouldn't work as it requires SSL on the origin server as well.

Comment: I've set it to Flexible 3 days ago; still being greeted with the same error message NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID - I have flushed my DNS as well.

Comment: @user29036 I think Choo is right about the server not being there.